# Two variables are not equal to, and not greater than, and not less than at the same time?

Tags: javascript

I wrote a binary search for my array in javascript, and found a strange behavrior of comparing two variables:

```
$ node
> a='10000@qq.com'
'10000@qq.com'
> b=100080
100080

> a==b
false
> a>b
false
> a<b
false

> typeof a
'string'
> typeof b
'number'
```

in this case: **a** is not equal to **b**, and **a** is not greater than **b**, and **a** is not less than **b**, which I think should not happen at the same time.

This is the reason why my binary search gone into death loop.

After I convert all the variables **toString()**, this problem gone.

My question is: How could this happen?

Comment: `After I convert all the variables toString(), this problem gone` - do that then

Comment: `<` and `>` make use of [abstract relational comparison](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison). Given a number and a string (step 6), the string will be convert to a number. In this case, that results in `NaN`, which in turn results in an answer of `undefined` when compared.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski It should be an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<` and `>` make use of [Abstract Relational Comparison](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison).

When given a number and a string (step 6), the string will be converted to a number. In this case, that results in `NaN` because of the `@qq.com`.

```
'10000@qq.com' < 100080         // initial
Number('10000@qq.com') < 100080 // step 6.a
NaN < 100080
```

This results in an `undefined` result:

> 6.e. If *nx* is **NaN**, return **undefined**.

Which [`<` and `>`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-relational-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation) then replace with `false`.

> 8. If *r* is **undefined**, return **false**. Otherwise, return *r*.

---

Why `NaN` results in `undefined` or `false` is at least in part because `NaN` is setup to never be considered equal to anything, including itself. That's why `isNaN()` is defined.

```
NaN === NaN // false
isNaN(NaN)  // true
```